# Simple 301 redirect doesn't work in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to create a 301 redirect from `/fr` to `/` - seems simple enough, but for some reason it's not happening.

In `.htaccess` I have:

```
Redirect 301 /fr /
```

Also tried with the full path, same result (no redirect happens):

```
Redirect 301 /fr http://example.com/
```

This is a Laravel application (though I don't think that should be relevant here).

EDIT: here's the full .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    Redirect 301 /fr /
</IfModule>
```

I'm aware that I can do the redirect within Laravel, but I want to do it in `.htaccess` because I will have more rules here.

Comment: Does `/fr/` directory have another .htaccess? Make sure this is your topmost rule.

Comment: Does `/fr` map to a physical directory?

Comment: If this is a Laravel project then presumably you also have other mod_rewrite directives? You should avoid mixing redirects from both modules. Please include your complete `.htaccess` file.

Comment: No, /fr is just a Laravel route, there's no physical directory or separate .htaccess.

Comment: @MrWhite Added the full .htaccess. Note that this rule is at the end, but when I put it at the start (right after RewriteEngine On) it still doesn't work.

Comment: Mixing RewriteRules and Redirects can be a tricky thing. Suggest you do this redirect using a RewriteRule instead. `RewriteRule ^fr$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]` - try and place that before the front controller rewrites.

Comment: Presumably mod_rewrite is enabled and the other mod_rewrite directives are working?